# Adding/Appending each items SimplecartJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplecart

I'm using a js plugin cart for my website called [Simplecartjs](http://simplecartjs.org/) and I'm trying to append my items in a `div`, but when the page loads, the `div` does not show up

```
simpleCart.each(function(item) {
    $('#test').append( item.get('quantity') +" "+ item.get('name').trim()+", ")
});
```

Comment: What do you mean no success?  Have you tried console.log() for the $('#test').length, item.get's to make sure your element exists and your getting the data you expect?

Comment: The problem is when i try to console log in my browser developer tools it works fine, but than when i try put the code directlly in the source of the page it doesnt do nothing.

Comment: Then do a console log on simpleCart.  That would make me think it does not exist (at the time of execution)

Comment: yes i did, it gave me this function:
`function (options) {
     // shortcut for simpleCart.ready
     if (isFunction(options)) {
      return simpleCart.ready(options);
     }

     // set options
     if (isObject(options)) {
      return simpleCart.extend(settings, options);
     }
    }`

Comment: So it's a function.  You'll probably have to invoke it first then.  If you know what "options" are you might do simpleCart(options).each(....) or maybe just try simpleCart().each(...)